# docker-compose fails to change ownership on ubuntu 22.04.3 on VMware Workstation

Tags: ubuntu, chown, docker-compose

VMware Workstation: 16.2.5/17.0.2

Ubuntu: 20.04.6/22.04.3

Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:12.1-slim

WORKDIR /root

RUN groupadd -f ernie-1001 -g 1001 \
    && groupadd -f ernie-1000 -g 1000 \
    && useradd -ms /bin/bash ernie -g 1001 -G 1000 \
    && printf "ernie:ernie" | chpasswd \
    && adduser ernie sudo \
    && printf "ernie ALL= NOPASSWD: ALL\\n" >> /etc/sudoers
```

On a fresh new Ubuntu 22.04.3 installation we run the following sequence of commands and expect exactly this output:

```
$ sudo apt install docker-compose
$ sudo docker build . -t strange:1.0
$ sudo docker run -it --name strangebase strange:1.0
root@d031fe5152e4:~# su ernie
ernie@d031fe5152e4:/root$ cd
ernie@d031fe5152e4:~$ ls -all
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 2 ernie ernie-1001 4096 Aug 19 04:16 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root  root       4096 Aug 19 04:16 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 ernie ernie-1001  220 Apr 23 21:23 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r-- 1 ernie ernie-1001 3526 Apr 23 21:23 .bashrc
-rw-r--r-- 1 ernie ernie-1001  807 Apr 23 21:23 .profile
ernie@d031fe5152e4:~$
```

What we get instead:

```
$ sudo apt install docker-compose
$ sudo docker build . -t strange:1.0
$ sudo docker run -it --name strangebase strange:1.0
root@d031fe5152e4:~# su ernie
ernie@d031fe5152e4:/root$ cd
ernie@d031fe5152e4:~$ ls -all
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 2 root  root 4096 Aug 19 04:16 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root  root       4096 Aug 19 04:16 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root  220 Apr 23 21:23 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root 3526 Apr 23 21:23 .bashrc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root  807 Apr 23 21:23 .profile
ernie@d031fe5152e4:~$
```

The ernie home directory (i.e. /home/ernie) is still owned by `root` for some reason, which should not be the case, should it?

I have tried it on a couple of machines with the same result. Strangely enough previously installed ubuntu_22.04 VMs work as expected.

I also tried throwing `RUN chown -R ernie:ernie /home/ernie` into the Dockerfile for good measure, but to no avail.

Am I doing something terribly wrong here? Has someone experienced anything similar as of recent?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a particular bug, whereby a tar archive created by a docker export command is missing ownership information (**all files are owned by root**). If this archive is then used to recreate a filesystem for unprivileged processes (like via docker import or just unpacking it and chrooting), they can fail with a permission denied error or in some other ways.

This bug happens when a package is built with Go older than 1.19: this version of Go introduced a unix build tag that is used by upstream to determine if it should add UNIX-specific attributes into an archive. Older Go versions silently ignore this source code, and the result is missing UIDs and GIDs in tar archives.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/docker.io-app/+bug/2029523.